# Using Python webpage(with necessary files) offline

Tags: python, python-2.7

Could you help me with this below script, please?

I am trying to store webpage with it's files offline to open them without internet connection using Python. I can copy the source codes of the target page into a file and save it as “example.html” in local PC. but my code is not saving files whenever i trying to open saved html file using python browser it's loading necessary files from the internet and it takes too much time to load (very slow).

This the a part of the original codes:

```
import urllib2, codecs

def download(site):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(site)
    html_input = response.read()
    return html_input

def derealitivise(site, html_input):
    active_html = html_input.replace('<head>', '<head> <base href='+site+'>')
    return active_html

def main(site, output_filename):
    #try:
    site_url = site.encode("utf-8")
    html_input = download(site_url)
    #active_html = derealitivise(site_url, active_html)
    header = "<head> <base href="+site_url+">"
    active_html = html_input.replace('<head>', header)
    #output_file = open (output_filename, "w")
    #output_file = codecs.open(output_filename, "wb", "utf-8-sig")
    #output_file.write(active_html.encode("utf-8"))
    #output_file.close()
    with open(output_filename, 'w') as fid:
        fid.write(active_html)   
    return "OK"
```

Comment: probably there are absolute references in the html-file.

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes i am inserting that on header, but in my case i need to store only one exact url page locally with its images and files, i was trying different script also scrapy but it is doing the same joy not storing images. i searched online regarding this but no use... please help: give me sample script Thanks